Windows stuck in bitlocker recovery after Ubuntu's boot-repair
I have a Dell XPS15 laptop which was happily dual-booting into Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10 until recently. Here is a rough timeline of what happened:

Laptop ran out of battery
Afterwards, it could only boot into Windows
I tried to repair this problem by booting to Ubuntu 22.04 from USB and running boot-repair (this did not fix it)
I found this answer that explained how to add the Ubuntu boot option (which had been deleted for some reason). I added a boot option for Ubuntu and made it the default.
Laptop now boots into the Ubuntu partition without issue, but when I try to boot into Windows, it starts Bitlocker recovery, then stops and displays a blue screen with "There was a problem. Restart your PC to try again." and error code 8007139f.

I tried installing boot-repair to use it to repair the Windows boot, but the option to repair Windows boot files is greyed out. In fact, it only has Ubuntu available under the "OS to boot by default" dropdown.
Previously to switch between Ubuntu and Windows, I needed to switch from "AHCI" (Ubuntu) to "RAID On" (Windows), which I'm still doing.
GRUB version is 2.04-1ubuntu26.17. I don't know what GRUB version I had before these problems started.

This is a windows or hardware (as in BIOS) problem so off topic. "Laptop now boots into the Ubuntu partition without issue,Laptop now boots into the Ubuntu partition without issue, " so as we only support Ubuntu it is off topic. Best advice: check all mandatory settings for using BL. Like TPM.

hi @sam-jaques since Ubuntu is booting up just fine, you should post this question on another Stack Exchange site: https://superuser.com. Thanks.

This question is similar to: Tried to install both Windows and Ubuntu, now neither will boot. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
